# How to delete all events from the default calendar

Tags: swift, ekevent, ekeventstore

How can I delete all events in the default calendar when a button is tapped?

This is my current code

```
     @IBAction func deleteEvents(_ sender: UIButton) {

         eventStore.calendars(for: .event).removeAll()
      }
```

The first problem it's not the current calendar. The second problem is that I get the following error:

**Error:**

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `removeAll` method.

You need to use the methods of `EKEventStore` to query and remove the desired events.

At a high level you need to:

1. Request authorization to access calendar events.
2. Get a reference to desired the `EKCalendar`.
3. Create a predicate for the events you wish to query. You need a date range and the calendar.
4. Enumerate the events that match the predicate.
5. Delete each enumerated event.

All of the needed APIs are in the `EKEventStore` class. See its documentation for specifics.